# How many objects are eligible for garbage collector?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

How many objects are eligible for garbage collection when the main method of the Tester class reaches its end? My impression is that the answer is two, particularly a1, b1. However I have found somewhere as corect answer, that only a1 object is eligible. I think that since we have not asigned b1 as member variable in a2 an b1 is assigned to null before main ends, it should be collected by garbage collector. What is true?

```
class B {
}

class A {
    static B b1;
    B b2;
}

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b1 = new B();
        B b2 = new B();
        A a1 = new A();
        A a2 = new A();
        a1.b1 = b1;
        a1.b2 = b1;
        a2.b2 = b2;
        a1 = null;
        b1 = null;
        b2 = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object initially assigned to the method scope variable `b1` is not eligible for collection because the reference to it in `Class A` is **static**.  It does not expire with that particular instance of a1.  It is a sneaky bit of wonky java syntax that `a1.b1` and `A.b1` are the same reference, but it is what it is.  That reference remains live until the class A is un-loaded/the JVM exists, regardless of what happens to any instance of A such as a1.

The code assigns the pointer `b1` in the method to null, but it does not assign `A.b1` to null.

Answer (score 0):

well the only reference that you haven't nullified is `a2`. your answer will be whatever objects that you can't trace to from `a2`

so you have `a2`, and `b2` is referenced by `a2.b2`

`a1` and (in the scope of your `main` method) can't, and are therefore garbage collected.

actaually, affe is right, `b1` is static, and is therefore reachable.

Answer (score 0):

- `a2` - since it was not nullified
- `b2` (the original object assigned to `b2`) - since it is held by a2
- `b1` (the original object assigned to `b1`) - since it's held in a `static` variable